# Error occurs while installing Groovy IDE in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, groovy

I am using Eclipse 3.7.0, and trying to install Groovy: I used this Link: [Groovy](http://dist.springsource.org/milestone/GRECLIPSE/e3.5/)

While installing by following instructions from that link, I got an error like this.

```
Error Message:

    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    Software being installed: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.0.0.xx-20091027-1400-e34 (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.xx-20091027-1400-e34)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I don't believe there's a release build of the Groovy Eclipse plug-in for Eclipse 3.7.  However, I've been using the dev builds of the plug-in for many versions and it's been extremely stable, so I'd recommend trying the dev build.  The appropriate update site for 3.7 would be http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.7/